# Having trouble editing Torrc

Tags: windows, configuration

I have downloaded and installed the Tor bundle for Windows and all is working fine. I would like to configure it so that it restricts my IP address to Australia only.

I have read the [edit my torrc](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#torrc) entry and have located the `Data/Tor/torrc` file, but how do I actually edit It? I am an ordinary user - not advanced - so I really have no idea what I'm doing. What program do I open the file in? When I opened it in notepad (you're all probably laughing out loud!), this is how it read:

```
 # This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be
 # preserved

 # The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor
 # will ignore it

 DataDirectory C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor
 DirReqStatistics 0
 GeoIPFile C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip
```

I have spent hours reading everything I can to work out how to edit it on my own, but I unfortunately I don't have the necessary knowledge and experience to understand what I'm reading. I know I have to put `{au}` somewhere, but where and how? Could somebody please tell me the *exact* steps to take so that I can configure Tor to always make me look like I have an Australian IP.

I'll be grateful for any replies.

Comment: Save it to Ansi type of file without the .txt

Answer (score 5):

Open Data\Tor\torrc-defaults in Notepad. Now move the cursor at the end of the file and insert a new line (Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Write `ExitNodes {au}`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and probably write also `StrictNodes 1` (you choose only nodes from AU and when there are none the Tor connection fails). Next step is to restart Tor and the settings become effective.

Comment: is it possible to write "ExitNodes IP", if I want to set up exit my data from this particular IP?

Comment: Please add a new question.